# How to insert return value from templatetag to {% if - again

Tags: django, django-templates

Ok, i write this:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_something(data, var1, var2):
    if data:
        if var1:
            if var2:
                return { 'variable': True }
return return { 'variable': False }
```

but this:

```
{% get_something 1 0 1 %}
{% if not variable %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

is still not working... Always show "..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to return the value directly and use something like this:

```
{% get_something 1 0 1 as variable %}
{% if not variable %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

I think it's not the goal of a template tag to update the global template context as it's very hard to see that the context gets updated as a user of your template tag.

Comment: This does not appear to work (anymore?): `'get_something' received too many positional arguments`. I've also tried it using `{% with env=envname %}`, but it does not appear to call the templatetag. (Django 1.6.5).

Comment: @blueyed if you use `@register.assignment_tag` instead of `@register.simple_tag` it should work as expected. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags). Keep in mind that this is deprecated as of Django 1.9.